# jQuery AJAX post to PHP for PDO INSERT not working with variables $('#id').val()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am showing 3 code-snippets.
Approach 1 and 2 do NOT work
The 3rd code IS WORKING.

********* not working1 start **************

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#sending').click(function(){   
// just 4 testing:
//var txtBoxVal = $('#TextBox1').val(); 
// alert(txtBoxVal); ==> ok: showing the value I want to send & INSERT into database via PDOinsertpost.php

     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./PDOinsertpost.php",                                                                                         
                data: 'postVal1=' + $('#TextBox1').val(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#reshow').html(msg);
                }

            }); // end Ajax Call
                // now trigger a reload via the click-function:             
            window.location.reload();
           }); //end event handler .click function 

    }); //end document.ready

</script>
```

********* not working1 end **************

now the approach with the variable inside the $.ajax (not working as well):

********* not working2 start **************

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#sending').click(function(){   
var txtBoxVal = $('#TextBox1').val();
 // an alert - just 4 testing:
// alert(txtBoxVal); // ok: showing the value I want to send & INSERT into database via PDOinsertpost.php

     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./PDOinsertpost.php",                                                                                         
                data: 'postVal1=' + txtBoxVal,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#reshow').html(msg);
                }

            }); // end Ajax Call
                // now trigger a reload via the click-function:             
            window.location.reload();
           }); //end event handler .click function 

    }); //end document.ready

</script>
```

********* not working2 end **************

and now the "hardcoded", working version (?courious for me, that this one is working - but the others do not...)

********* the working1 start **************

```
<script>
 var txtBoxVal = "some hardcoded string for testing";
 $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#sending').click(function(){   

     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./PDOinsertpost.php",                                                                                         
                data: 'postVal1=' + txtBoxVal,
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#reshow').html(msg);
                }

            }); // end Ajax Call
                // now trigger a reload via the click-function:             
            window.location.reload();
           }); //end event handler .click function 

    }); //end document.ready

</script>
```

********* the working1 end **************

Additional Info.: in the meantime I figured out, that an empty value is working with the two "not-working" code-snippets with $('#id').val(),
this means: a blank value is inserted in the database.

Am I searching at the wrong place? 
Do I need to do some htmlentities - stuff or something within the .php file with the PDO-INSERT?

I hope, some useful information can be gathered by this post - for me, as well as for others.

Thanks in advance,
-Flow.

Comment: Will you please post the associated HTML? If you have multiple #TextBox1 IDs, which is invalid, the val() would be an array.

Comment: And do you have `$('#TextBox1')` element? Console log the value, before call the ajax.

Comment: You are reloading the page (in all your examples...) while the ajax request has not yet finished. Very risky and buggy approach. And if you reload any way, you don't need ajax.

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: hello - thak you for trying to help! I have to say, that the original code is about 500 lines long and it is working on my virtual LAMP server. But when I deployed it to my webspace, I got the problem with inserting the textarea values to the database.

Comment: The id's are given only once per html-element, and I focused on making the entry work in only a single one via the ('#id").val method at first - and leave the rest of the entries "hardcoded" (the hardcoded ones do work - what makes me a headache...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 big problems here:

1. You are reloading the page (in all your examples...) while the ajax request has not yet finished. That is a very risky and buggy approach as you cannot be sure that your php script will finish correctly. And if you reload any way, you don't need ajax.
2. You are not escaping your value so user input can break the query string. The easiest solution for that is to use an object so that jQuery encodes it correctly automatically:
   `data: { 'postVal1': $('#TextBox1').val() },`

I also don't see you cancelling the default form submit, but as the third example works, I assume that the button / `#sending` element is not a submit button. If not, you would need to take care of that as well.

**Edit:** As you are using a submit button, you need to prevent the regular form submit:

```
$('#sending').click(function(event){
   // prevent the default form submit
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
```

Comment: to 1)   -  yes, you're right. It is a forum-post, and when it's done, the user shall see it right away in the refreshed page. How else shall this be done? to2) are the {} brackets responsible for the creating of an object? (seems so). I guess, I have to do something additional within my .php file for getting the values out of the object as well, do I?

Comment: the #sending element is a submit button " <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="sending" id="sending" value="Insert Posting" /> Thanx for your advice so far - it gives me at least a hint what to do next.

Comment: @flowfab In that case the default from submit needs to be cancelled, see my edit.

Comment: @flowfab About the object, no, jQuery will send that to the server where you can get it like you do now, in `$_POST['postVal1']`. If you need more key-value pairs, just separate them with commas.

Answer (score 1):

without the "window.location.reload();" it seems to work!
@jeroen had probably the right explanation: the reload disturbed the process!
(but it didn't on my virtual home-server ... (may be, because of other processing-times...  ))